# Angular 2 can't set default value for ControlValueAccessor component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

Scaled down plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/gGCiYjcq70xaewn3n22F?p=preview

```
@Input() model: any;

propagateChange = (_: any) => {};

registerOnChange(fn) {
  this.propagateChange = fn;
}

registerOnTouched() {}

writeValue(value: any) {

  if (value !== undefined) {
    this.model = value;
  }
}

ngOnInit() {

  // Sets the model properly, but it doesn't show up in the view or outside of the component
  if (!this.model && this.isRequired) {
    this.model = options[0];
  }

  this.propagateChange(this.model);
}
```

Usage:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <custom-select #fuel="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.fuel" [options]="fuels" [isRequired]="true" name="fuel"></custom-select>
</form>
```

I've implemented `ControlValueAccessor` for a custom select, but I can't get it to set a default value when the component is first initialised in the `ngOnInit` method. The `model` is set inside of the component correctly, but it's not reflected in the view or outside of the component. But if I then change the value by selecting some other option it works.. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: I guess it's a change detection issue because `ngOnInit()` is called from change detection. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That's a bummer. Really important to get this working hmm.. If you happen to find a solution I'll reward you with a solid bounty. Till then I guess I'll have to try everything there is to try..

Comment: I don't have deep knowledge of forms. Perhaps someone else.

Comment: I guess you should set up your default value inside of `writeValue` method. https://plnkr.co/edit/k6WpY4ERzH3fZ2QgZIz2?p=preview Because `writeValue` is always firing from NgModel component and it happens after ngOnInit within your component. You can also see how i'm checking model via setter property (`@Input() set model(val)`)

Comment: @yurzui Feels a bit hacky though, doesn't it? Surely life cycle hooks should be able to fire it as well?

Comment: @yurzui Your example only updates the component view, but the outside isn't notified, any idea why?

Comment: registerOnChange function is running after your control initialization. So function `propagateChange` hasn't effect in ngOninit it is still `(_: any) => {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to do it working

```
@Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter();

ngOnInit() {
 ...
 this.ngModelChange.emit(this.model);
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/VQJSDLU9TP2rVBmNeTNr?p=preview

Comment: I did `@Input('ngModel') model: any;`, is that correct? I don't understand how `model` can be connected to the `ngModel` in `<custom-select [(ngModel)]="test"></custom-select>` if I don't do that? Because the input is no longer `model` since I've added `ControlValueAccessor`, which means any checks for `this.model` in the component should theoretically not work since the input is `ngModel` now. So with `@Input() model: any;` I don't understand how it can still work..

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the cleanest way:

```
registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
  this.propagateChange = fn;
  if (this.value == null) {
   this.propagateChange('defautlValue');
  }
}
```