# How do I set the default form control value in this situation?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I am currently working on reusable components with custom form field controls.

I have this custom autocomplete control that returns an object as its value, and then my reusable component, using this custom control, passes one of the object properties to my main form as a string. Here is a blitz to check it out:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-custom-autocomplete-jlkj9q

This works fine in one direction, control --> reusable-field --> form.

Here is how I update the form value from my reusable component:

```
  ngOnInit(){

      this.state = new FormControl(null);

      // any time the form field value changes update the parent of any change
      this.state.valueChanges
              .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy))
              .subscribe(value => {
                if(!!value && !!value.name){
                  this.onChange(value.name) //pass only the state.name to the ControlValueAccessor
                  this.onTouched();
                }
                else{
                  this.onChange(value)
                  this.onTouched();
                }
      });
  }
```

Now, when I set a default value to the reusable component field, the control is updated correctly, but the form value is not. I tried calling the `onChange()` method on the `ngOnInit` with the value to be passed to the main form, but nothing happened. Then I tried to set the default value on the ngAfterViewInit and call the `onChange` like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){

      let defaultValue = {
                  "name": "Arkansas",
                  "population": "2.978M",
                  "flag": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Flag_of_Arkansas.svg"
                };

      this.state.setValue(defaultValue);    
      this.onChange(defaultValue);
}
```

but this doesn't work either.
What am I missing here? Any clues?

Comment: seems like a weird choice to be mixing ngModel at one level and reactive forms at another. Why not go reactive all the way down

Comment: Well, I don't know if I have a good answer for that. I followed angular material's guide. This is what it suggests, it works, so I kept it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For quick workaround add

```
setTimeout(() => this.state.setValue(this.defaultValue), 0);
```

at the end of `ngOnInit` in reusable form field.

Comment: It works on the AfterViewInit hook not on on the NgOnit. Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks @TomaszFlis ! This post also answers the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585566/angular-2-cant-set-default-value-for-controlvalueaccessor-component

Answer (score 0):

a couple of things...

1. your form group's default value is overriding the one provided by your form, the `writeValue` method is called at the end of the `ngOnInit` hook. You can get around this by simply calling `setValue` in your reusable form in a later hook
2. you're using onPush change detection in your app component in your blitz. This means that only certain things will trigger change detection, and a child component updating a reactive form value is NOT one of them.  This is why you're not seeing the change be reflected in your templates.  This isn't a big deal if you're just interested in the form value and not in displaying it on screen, but it IS a big deal if you want to display it, as if you remove onPush change detection, you will begin seeing expression changed errors, as a child updating something in the parents template during initialization violates unidirectional data flow.  Getting around this is a bit more difficult.  The true answer here is that your parent form really should be the one providing the default value.

Comment: I know that  change detection is a problem here. My plan B was to set the default value on my main form, although I should use the whole object to pass the correct value all the way through. I have tried setting the value on a later hook(ngAfterViewInit), but this didn't work, until I used the `setTimeout` workaround from the answer above...

Comment: a timeout going off DOES trigger change detection, i generally try to avoid is at a practice though

Comment: Yeah, I know... I can't think of anything else, except setting the value on the main form, but then I would have to deal with two controls, one that updates the reusable component with an object and the actual form control that accepts a string...